Set subgrid command button visiblity based on which parent table they are added using Power FX formula
I have a custom entity (c1) referenced from both CRM opportunity and quote.
In simple terms, the quote has a lookup to c1 and also the opportunity has a lookup to c1.
Then, I have added a subgrid of a second custom entity c2 which is a child of c1 into both opportunity and quote using a quick view form.
This is working perfectly on both opportunity and quote records. When I select the value for c1 lookup the subgrid populates related c2 records.
Now I want to add two subgrid buttons to the subgrid of c2 records. However, one button is to run a javascript on the opportunity record for the selected records. And the other button is for quote records.
Only one button should be visible on the subgrid and the condition should be based on which table's record the subgrid is in.
eg: when the user is working on the opportunity record, he can set c1 lookup value and see the related c2 records in the subgrid and see the specific subgrid command button for opportunity.
when the user is working on the quote record, he can set c1 lookup value and see the related c2 records in the subgrid and see the specific subgrid command button for quote only.

I have added a new power fx command button. so there is no javascript support in the visibility section. Therefore the answer has to be a power fx formula to check the table name of the current record or something like that.
Please share your thoughts on this
